# Are mission/payload specialists less capable of managing a spacecraft?

Tags: training

In the movie "Gravity", the main character, Dr. Ryan Stone is portrayed as being knowledgeable about some field of science, but not especially good at managing a spacecraft. The movie has her as a [Mission Specialist](http://gravitymovie.wikia.com/wiki/Mission_Specialist), though it's speculated that a Payload Specialist would more accurately describe her role.

In real life, are mission specialists and payload specialists less capable of handling spacecrafts than other members of the crew? What standards are expected of the different roles? For example, if nothing had gone wrong except the death of all of their crew-mates (a less severe scenario than that in "Gravity"), would a payload specialist be expected to safely return to earth without a rescue mission?

[Related question, but less specific](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2405/625)

Comment: Still looks like an exact duplicate. The proportion stuff can be asked in a new question.

Comment: Would not be a duplicate if you wanted to know more about STS / Orbiter used in Gravity, than auto-piloted crafts which are well covered in the other question. So feel free to edit your question.